# How to click a button inside a modal after opens it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I really want to know, how can I click a button inside a Bootstrap modal after I've open it by clicking its link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myid">
```

Buttons have ids', so I think I can click the button using **js**, but I don't really know how to deal with this.

Could I use a function such as `$("#buttonid").click();` in the `data-target` after the modal call?

I tried with no results. 
Any help would be appreciate

Here is the button code:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttonid" name="Profile" href="#">
```

Comment: Could you add the html code of your button as well ? Cannot figure out the `data-target` part.

Comment: Note that data-target is used to indicates the modal id

Comment: Is it inside a FORM, the button ?

Comment: Nope, i use them to show a content in a part of the modal based on the button click of the user

Comment: I think that the info given by you is incomplete. Can you describe the whole situation? Like what exactly you want to happen? Does the button has click event bound to it? If yes, at what instance you bind the click event? And so on...

Comment: I just want to click that specific butto inside the modal, just after the modal opens ( it opens thanks to the <a> link i wrote before

Comment: This code <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myid"> is used to open modal without js.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to trigger the click of the button, as opposed to invoking the *effect* of clicking the button?

Comment: Yeah, is beacause of my necessities. I have 3 buttons inside, that change the content of my modal depends on the click. When i first open the modal no button is clicked so the modal has the buttons and the rest of it white

Comment: refer this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126319/pass-data-into-a-modal-using-javascript/38129417#38129417

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
 $("#newBtn").trigger("click");  
});

 $("#newBtn").on("click",function(){
 alert("button inside modal clicked");
 
 })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   You can make the button hidden by adding class hidden to button.
       <button type="button" id="newBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">clicked on modal open</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the trigger on the modal shown event

```
$('#myid').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#buttonid").trigger('click');
});
```